# В чем разница между информационной системой и программным обеспечением?

Tags: терминология, теория, информатика

Требуется спроектировать информационную систему. Но не могу понять отличия между ПО и ИС.

Comment: думаю, эта разница существенна разве что для бюрократически настроенных дедушек-преподавателей, поскольку вопрос скорее из области софистики. Тем, кто пишет софт это в подавляющем большинстве случаев безразлично.

Comment: [Информационная система](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) включает не только ПО. И далеко не любое ПО может использоваться в ИС. Компонентами ИС могут быть СУБД, системы управления контентом, но не блокнот, сапёр и пасьянс косынка.

Comment: @DreamChild я бы тут поспорила, но StackOverflow не место для споров ;) Боюсь, что вопрос будет закрыт, как провокационный и стимулирующий флуд...

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya, если все мы будем слепо следовать всем таким правилам, то сайт очень скоро превратится во что-то очень напоминающее английское кладбище. / IMHO -- есть что сказать коллеге -- говори /

Comment: Из комментариев можно многое для себя почерпнуть, возможно именно он и окажется ответом!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПО - программное обеспечение - является группой программ, обеспечивающих решение некоторой задачи (учет фантиков от конфет), ведение некоторого процесса (просмотр фотографий котиков), работу некоторого отдела (бухгалтерии) и т.п. Эта самая группа программ - безымянна, ПО не может иметь своего имени. Нельзя говорить ПО "Фантики", ПО "Котики" или ПО "Бухгалтерия" - это попросту звучит не по-русски. Вместо этого говорят ПО учета фантиков, ПО просмотра фотографий, ПО бухгалтерии.

Поскольку у ПО нет имени, всегда можно обозвать его как-нибудь по-другому. ПО просмотра фотографий вполне может превратиться в ПО просмотра котиков - или войти в состав ПО комнаты отдыха. Если там находится один и тот же просмотрщик изображений Windows - то это будет одно и то же ПО, как его не назови.

ИС - информационная система, напротив, всегда именная. Вполне могут существовать ИС "Фантики", ИС "Котики" и ИС "Бухгалтерия". Впрочем, ИС просмотра фотографий также имеет право на существование (здесь название системы  - это и есть "ИС просмотра фотографий"). Также для ИС не требуется, чтобы для ее компонентов существовал какой-то объединяющий признак - вполне допускается существование ИС "Фантики и Бухгалтерия", если, конечно же, такая ИС будет хоть кому-нибудь нужна.

С другой стороны, имя для ИС придумывается только тем, кто ее распространяет. Нельзя купить ИС "Фантики", а потом написать в документах, что куплена ИС "Пожиратель конфет" - это совершенно разные ИС, даже если они составлены из одних и тех же компонентов (хотя одна ИС все же может войти в состав другой - но обычно такие ИС называют все-таки не системами, а подсистемами).

Еще одно отличие ИС от ПО - ИС может содержать компоненты, не являющиеся программами или данными к ним. К примеру, в состав ИС, которая предоставляет пассажирам на вокзале расписание поездов, вполне могут входить информационные киоски. ПО же, как следует из названия, может содержать только программы, иначе будет зваться уже АПО (аппаратно-программное обеспечение).

### UPD

> Суть в том, что ИС более широкое понятие, чем ПО. Как минимум ИС помимо ПО включает в себя инструкции по эксплуатации и др. административные регламенты, а также определенный состав технических средств. –  avp

Да, верное замечание. Я бы его несколько обобщил. ИС, как именованная сущность, существует до тех пор, пока существует пакет документов, ее определяющий. В этот пакет включаются в том числе всевозможные инструкции и др. административные регламенты.

В то же время ПО не требует документов для своего существования.

Comment: Суть в том, что ИС более широкое понятие, чем ПО. Как минимум ИС помимо ПО включает в себя инструкции по эксплуатации и др. административные регламенты, а также определенный состав технических средств.

Comment: Скажем так, у меня стоит цель спроектировать информационную систему электронного архива центра робототехники. Архив хранит проекты центра: данные проекта - наименование, шифр, авторы и т.д. и прикрепленные материалы - исходные коды, 3д-модели и т.д. Является ли это информационной системой?

Comment: Если вы составите комплект документов на нее - то да. Если это учебное задание, то пояснительная записка в требуемом формате сойдет за этот самый комплект документов :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! ...Попал в затруднительную ситуацию, когда пытался понять "ИС или не ИС". Исходя из регламентирующих НПА не сильно разобрался. "Простым языком" получилось более доходчиво - теперь можно "покопать" в этом направлении.